# Not supported record types for CSV import in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Can I get a name of Unsupported record types that cannot be imported using CSV in Netsuite.
Item fulfillment is the 1 know...
Please advise.

Can I get a name of Unsupported record types that cannot be imported using CSV in Netsuite.
Item fulfillment is the 1 know...
Please advise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of supported records from suiteanswer id 10008

https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10008

So anything not listed on this page means not supported :D

From my experience, these are records that can't be imported using csv.

Transactions

- Item Fulfilment
- Item Receipt
- Customer Deposit
- Bank Transfer